# Class diagram generation from java/groovy code and exporting

Tags: java, grails, groovy, uml, class-diagram

I'm in the need of a eclipse plugin / or tool which can generate 
 class diagrams from my java/groovy code and vice versa. Actually it is a 
 groovy/grails project. The actual requirements are:

- I should be able to draw class diagram and generate code and generate class diagram 
  from existing code
- (Important) I have to export the generated class diagram in some format to share it 
  with my teammates, **so they can generate code from it**.

  Please suggest me a good solution.

  Thanks in advance.

Comment: not an answer but why do you want to share the diagram and not the code itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual paradigm for uml. Using Visual Paradign you generate UML diagrams of your and generate code, using UML diagrams

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please see the requirements mentioned as importan: Can i export diagram, and can i generate code from exported diagram?

Answer (score 0):

You can create diagrams, share it on CVS or by email but it is only possible with the java code. I don't think it exist for both groovy and java.

You have two options today which is to use a live code and model synchronization tool which is more integration level or a model driven tool which will generate all the code once the model has been completed.
I personally prefer the first live synchronization option because if the code is updated then my model will also be. It is painful to produce diagrams and then realize that at the implementation stage the development team has changed the code and that my diagrams are not anymore relevant !!

Comment: Lets say, i created the diagrams, the only option i get when exporting is to export as image. I can share the image with other, but can they load it and generate code from it? i don't think they can generate code with a PNG or GIF image of class diagram. So, i'm searching a way to export the class diagrams which can be imported to other projects and can be used to generate code. So looking for a tool which will allow creating UML and exporting it as a project so that it can be imported and used directly in another place.

Comment: You just need to export your model and your class diagram graphical representation. I use Omondo in my company. I export the the model .uml file and the class diagram graphical representation .ucd The trick I use it to have a model and then once it is exported the developer can click on the menu transform to Java. All your class diagram will become java immediately. Really easy and cool feature :-)